# About closed map beween schemes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Probabily it's trivial but I've no idea for a proof.

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y $ a continuous map between Topological Spaces, with $Im(f)$ closed in $Y$. I know 
there exist a covering $\{Y_i\}$ of $Y$ such that $\{f^{-1}(Y_i)\}$ is a covering of $X$ and $f: f^{-1}(Y_i) \rightarrow Y_i $ is closed. 
Is $f$ a closed function?

I suppose this is false, but i know it is true in the context of the Theory of Schemes (if $f: X \rightarrow Y $ a morphism between the schemes $X$ and $Y$, with $Im(f)$ closed in $Y$ and 
there exist a covering $\{Y_i\}$ of $Y$ such that $\{f^{-1}(Y_i)\}$ is a covering of $X$ and $f: f^{-1}(Y_i) \rightarrow Y_i $ is closed, then $f$ is a closed morphism ).

It seems clear if $Y$ is quasi-compact. Some help for a general proof?

Thank you!

Comment: Dear Joseph, what do your hypotheses "$f: f^{-1}(Y_i) \rightarrow Y_i $" mean?

Comment: I've edited, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is purely topological, the fact that you have the supplementary structure of a scheme on $Y$ is irrelevant.
The answer to the question is "no" if you consider an arbitrary covering $(Y_i)$ of $Y$: by taking for the $Y_i$'s the points of $Y$ (seen as singleton subsets of $Y$) you would conclude that every surjective  continuous map is closed, which is  false (cf. first projection $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$).
However if $(Y_i)$ is an open covering, the result is true, because $F\subset Y$ is closed if and only if all the $F\cap Y_i$ are closed in the relative topology of $Y_i$.